# Facebook FQL bug

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

```
SELECT eid, start_time, name FROM event WHERE (eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE (uid = me() AND start_time < 1317006752)))
```

This FQL query is supposed to return events that began before `1317006752`

However, it returns valid events IN ADDITION to this one

```
{
    "eid": 239526399426862,
    "start_time": 1317448800,
    "name": "Nick Grimshaw, The 2 Bears, S.C.U.M. & more! Friday 30th Sept, Only £4.50"
  }
```

Now correct me if I'm wrong, but `1317448800` is bigger than `1317006752`.

You might be able to verify this by going to the [event page](http://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=239526399426862), click on something (i.e not attend), then [run the query here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be the difference in timezone between the event creator and the active user.  Facebook provides this notice:

> Note that the start_time and end_time are the times that were inputted
>   by the event creator. Facebook Events have no concept of timezone, so,
>   in general, you can should not treat the value returned as occurring
>   at any particular absolute time. When an event is displayed on
>   facebook, no timezone is specified or implied.

Comment: the time difference is over 5 days when i tested this, which is bigger than any time zone difference

Answer (score 0):

Apparently start_time in event_member is used purely to speed up queries on event_member table which can return many results. Seems like it is not updated when the event's start_time is updated. Your query should be like the following to work properly, note the difference:

```
SELECT eid, start_time, name
  FROM event 
 WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid 
                 FROM event_member 
                WHERE uid = me() AND start_time < 1317006752)
   AND start_time < 1317006752
```

I agree this is a bug though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today getting upcoming events :
The correct FQL should be

```
SELECT eid,name,description,location,start_time,end_time,pic_big FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE start_time>=PLACE_UNIX_TIMESTAMP AND uid=PLACE_UID_HERE) ORDER BY start_time ASC
```

**EDIT**

Fetching the result of this query is done by :

```
$sql = '/fql?q=SELECT+eid,name,description,location,start_time,end_time,pic_big+FROM+event+WHERE+eid+IN+(SELECT+eid+FROM+event_member+WHERE+start_time>={time}+AND+uid={id})+ORDER+BY+start_time+ASC';
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $sql '&access_token={token}');
$data = json_decode($fql_query_result,true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
```

Important to add the JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING option to the json_decode to prevent the eid of becoming a shortend float representation

**EDIT 2:**
As the const JSON_BIG... is only available from php5.4.X+ :

```
if (defined('JON_BIGINT_AS_STRING')) return json_decode($fql_query_result,true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
return json_decode(preg_replace('/([^\\\])":([0-9]{10,})(,|})/', '$1":"$2"$3', $fql_query_result),true);
```

source : http://www.pixelastic.com/blog/321:fix-floating-issue-json-decode-php-5-3

Comment: thx to  Anatoly for pointing out the start_time in the event_member table